# What does "visigraph" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've encountered a word in print which does not exist, and which Google isn't auto-correcting to an existing word. I wonder which word the author had meant to use.

Following is the sentence in which the word appears. It's from a fairly well-known novel "Foundation" by Isaac Asimov.

> At least, it amounted to an ultimatum, though a superficial reading of the **visigraphed** document would lead one to suppose that it was a friendly interchange of greetings between two potentates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a made up word invented by Issac Asimov to name some future means of transmitting a document from place to place. Presumably some form of futuristic fax or PDF! 
It is common in science fiction to give an invented name to such technologies for example *Warp Drive* in Star Trek.

Comment: That makes perfect sense in this context. I'm curious if you guessed or if you've also seen this word being used by Asimov elsewhere -- in other books of the series or in chapters I haven't read yet.

Comment: It does come up again, page 115 "visicasters".

Comment: I can't recall having seen Asimov use the word elsewhere, but I wouldn't be surprised if he did. My answer is based on over 60 years reading science fiction and a google search that throws up nothing relevant. It's not exactly guessing, more experience - making up words what SF authors do..

Comment: I just read that chapter and thought the same thing. I assumed it was a sort of fax or otherwise reproduced copy of a document. Visi (visual) graph (written)

Comment: It's a pretty cool word and since techies don't read too many novels, they wouldn't have thought to use it.

Comment: @Lambie "since techies don't read too many novels" I take exception to that! {grin}. I've been avidly reading all sorts of novels for over 60 years and I'm a retired electrical / software R&D engineer who still builds his own PCs from scratch.

Comment: @PeterJennings I salute you, sir. :)